# What does *.id mean in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am pretty new to Terraform. I am having some trouble trying to understand what terraform is doing here:

```
output "subnet_ids" {
  value = aws_subnet.private.*.id
}
```

In the aws_subnet resource block we have

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = element(split(",", var.cidrs), count.index)
  availability_zone = element(split(",", var.azs), count.index)
  count             = length(split(",", var.cidrs))

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name}-${count.index == 0 ? "a" : "b"}"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [availability_zone]
  }
}
```

What is being referred by `aws_subnet.private.*.id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the subnets using the `count` meta-argument [1]. This will result in having a list of `aws_subnet` resources. To access a single element of a list, you would usually have to specify an index in any other programming language. The same applies in terraform, so e.g., you can access a single element with `aws_subnet.private[0].id`. Terraform is providing you with a wildcard (`*`) also known as the `splat` expression [2] so you can fetch all the elements of a list instead of using the index to get one by one. I also think that is the old syntax and that `aws_subnet.private[*].id` should work as well. Basically, the splat expression is just a short version of a `for` loop which you would have to use otherwise to get all the elements of a list.

The `.id` part fetches the ID attribute of a subnet. You could do the same for any other attribute of that resource. So in short: the splat expression helps you get all the `.id` attributes from all the private subnets which were created using the `count` meta-argument.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count

[2] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat